# How to fix spacing-0 with other different spacing inline in bootstrap?

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive, spacing, bootstrap-5

I would like to set an element with a size padding 3 default but 0 from medium breakpoint because I need this spacing only for small devices

**This is my code with the error (I don't know why):**

```
<p class="p-3 p-md-0">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

**But if I test with other values it works and change well, so the problem could be the "zero" value?**

```
<p class="p-3 p-md-1">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I tested by adding a border the `p` and it works fine: https://codeply.com/p/Bc1GowDIur

Comment: hi zim, reloaded the page and your file works... i don't know why my code (the same) keeps the padding values :(

Comment: ok, solved! I've created a file to override the bootstrap variables, but I needed to add manually the first value zero into the map merge.